# Routing feature not inbuilt in Angular.min ?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, routes, ngroute

While going through angular.js I thought it to be a complete framework and all its features accessable eazily by only 1 js, i.e, "angular.min.js".

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>
```

But, to my surprise while going through implementing routing I found I still need an external js, i.e, "angular-route.min.js".

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

My question is couldn't the route feature also included in the angular.min.js file? Why do we need an external file for routing? If so, what are the other features for which angular needs external js files implemented for other tasks.

Comment: Most likely it was a design choice by the Angular team or developed laterally to the main project and later included hence why it's not in the angular core. There are a couple of other components such as $resource $ngRoute that need to be added along side the core.

Comment: $ngRoute is the one I have asked. Yep, $resource might be the other one.  ;)